How can I create a stored procedure in Postgresql?
For the following stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_parlay_modular(
    IN bet_pools TEXT[],              
    IN min_combined_odds NUMERIC,
    IN max_combined_odds NUMERIC
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    query TEXT;
    i INTEGER;
    j INTEGER;
    num_legs INTEGER := array_length(bet_pools, 1);
    odds_combination TEXT;
    quality_combination TEXT;
    bet_ids TEXT;
BEGIN
    odds_combination := 'p1.bet_decimal_odds';
    quality_combination := 'p1.bet_quality_score';
    bet_ids := 'p1.bet_id';

    FOR i IN 2..num_legs LOOP
        odds_combination := odds_combination || ' * COALESCE(p' || i || '.bet_decimal_odds, 1)';
        quality_combination := quality_combination || ' + COALESCE(p' || i || '.bet_quality_score, 0)';
        bet_ids := bet_ids || ', p' || i || '.bet_id AS bet_id_' || i;
    END LOOP;

    query := 'WITH ';

    FOR i IN 1..num_legs LOOP
        IF i > 1 THEN
            query := query || ', ';
        END IF;
        query := query || 'pool_' || i || ' AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bet_quality_score DESC, bet_decimal_odds DESC) AS rn FROM ' || bet_pools[i] || ')';
    END LOOP;

    query := query || ', combined_bets AS (SELECT ';

    FOR i IN 1..num_legs LOOP
        IF i > 1 THEN
            query := query || ', ';
        END IF;
        query := query || 'p' || i || '.bet_id AS bet_id_' || i || ', p' || i || '.bet_decimal_odds AS odds_' || i || ', p' || i || '.bet_quality_score AS quality_' || i;
    END LOOP;

    query := query || ', (' || odds_combination || ') AS combined_odds, (' || quality_combination || ') AS total_quality FROM pool_1 p1';

    FOR i IN 2..num_legs LOOP
        query := query || ' CROSS JOIN pool_' || i || ' p' || i;
    END LOOP;

    query := query || ' WHERE ';
    FOR i IN 1..(num_legs - 1) LOOP
        FOR j IN (i + 1)..num_legs LOOP
            IF (i > 1 OR j > 2) THEN
                query := query || ' AND ';
            END IF;
            query := query || 'p' || i || '.bet_id IS DISTINCT FROM p' || j || '.bet_id';
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    query := query || ' AND combined_odds BETWEEN ' || min_combined_odds || ' AND ' || max_combined_odds;

    query := query || ' ORDER BY total_quality DESC, combined_odds DESC LIMIT 1)';

    EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE parlay_result AS ' || query;

END $$;

I get the error:

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...5.5 ORDER BY total_quality DESC, combined_odds DESC LIMIT 1)

I've tried all different variations of fixes I've found for similar errors, which includes:

Adding semicolon
Removing semicolon
Changing parens/style

I've also asked ChatGPT-4o, DeepSeek Coder v2, Claude 3.5 Sonnet, etc. None of them returned a valid response, and their responses only exacerbated the errors. Thus, I am completely stumped. This is my first time working with stored procedures, so I'm not sure where to look or how to begin. I understand that the procedure itself is complex, but to my knowledge, the solution or cause of the error doesn't seem to be related to the inherent complexity of the query.
Thank you.

It sounds like you’re producing an invalid SQL query string. Have you tried debugging the value of query?

It seems like you are 1) using psycopg2 to 2) create a somewhat complex stored procedure which 3) dynamically generates and executes some SQL code. Debugging such a thing "big bang style" is nearly impossible. My advice would be to try to create the stored procedure manually, using psql, and to remove things until it passes, then put things back in again until it fails. That way, at least you have a sporting chance of seeing where the problem is. (If the error happens when running the procedure, not when creating it, I agree with @AndyRay ’s comment about checking the value of query ).

I confirm that the query (CTE) is a invalid SQL. You can check it addind :RAISE NOTICE query; before the execute and execute the procedure from command line
